# C#: Joining two Lists excluding duplicates

Tags: c#, list, join, concatenation

What is a simple effective way to take *List2* and add it to the end of *List1* - but in a way that only those items that are **not** already in *List1* before the concatenation - will be added to it?

**EDIT:**
I've been trying methods suggested in answers here, but I still get dupes added to List1! 
This is a code example:

```
// Assume the existence of a class definition for 'TheObject' which contains some 
// strings and some numbers.

string[] keywords = {"another", "another", "another"};
List<TheObject> tempList = new List<TheObject>();
List<TheObject> globalList = new List<TheObject>();

foreach (string keyword in keywords)
{
    tempList = // code that returns a list of relevant TheObject(s) according to
               // this iteration's keyword.
    globalList = globalList.Union<TheObject>(tempList).ToList();
}
```

When debugging - after the second iteration - globalList contain two copies of the exact same object of TheObject. Same thing happens also when I try implementing Edward Brey's solution...

**EDIT2:** 
I've modified the code that returns a new tempList, to also check if the returned items are already in the globalList (by doing !globalList.contains()) - it works now.  
Though, this is a work-around...

Comment: Does TheObject have Equals overridden? Otherwise, the default is reference equality, which won't work if tempList's items are newly created each time.

Comment: It's a class auto-generated by Linq to SQL from a table in a DB. I looked at the definition and haven't seen any Equals override. Should I create one? One that takes two object instances and compare each of their properties?

Comment: Or can I somehow change this default of 'by reference equality' to 'by value'?

Comment: Assuming you don't have duplicates in your starting `globalList`, you can use `Union` overload with the extra parameter and put the value comparison semantics in the class you derive from `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 4):

List1.Union(list2).For more examples goto http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: I tried:
List1 = List1.Union(List2).toList(); in a loop where List2 is different on each iteration - and items that are already in List1 still gets added to it...

Comment: that is strange.Try List1 = List1.Union(List2).Distinct()

Answer (score 2):

You can use the List's Union method like

```
List1.Union(list2);
```

Comment: Be sure to put .ToList() at the end!

Answer (score 1):

LINQ's `Union` will work if all of List1's items are distinct. Otherwise, to more precisely meet the stated goal, without requiring O(m*n) search time, you can use a hash set (replace `T` with the type of your list):

```
var intersection = new HashSet<T>(List1.Intersect(List2));
List1.AddRange(List2.Where(item => !intersection.Contains(item)));
```